# PHP Variable within For Loop

Tags: php, variables

Hi I have the following:

```
$q1 = $_POST["q2"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
```

What I'd like to do is put this within a `For` loop, as follows:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    $q1 = $_POST["q".$i.""];
}
```

I can add the variable to the `POST` part no problems but I cannot work out how to have the `1` next to the $q as a variable:

```
$q1 = $_POST["q".$i.""];
```

I'm sure it's simple but I cannot fathom it!

Comment: this should work `$_POST["q".$i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$q_arr = array(); //create empty array
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    if(isset($_POST["q".$i])) //first check existance of $_POST item with wanted key 
    $q_arr['q'.$i] =  $_POST["q".$i]; //store it in array

}
extract($q_arr);  //extract creates variables naming them as their key 
if(isset($q1)) //just for test 
echo $q1; //just for test
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
// As array:
$q[ $i ] = $_POST['q'.$i]; // this one is my prefered

// Or as object:
$q->$i = $_POST['q'.$i];
```

edit: removed the eval() version, You simply should not use that. The array one should work just fine :)

You cán use variable variables, but you shouldn't. It get very complicated real fast.

```
$name1 = 'myName'; 
$example = "name".$i;
echo $$example;
```

Comment: That did not work. `$a='a'; $b='b'; echo $a.$b;` will concat to 'ab' with a dot. I removed the example, it was bad practice anyway :)

Comment: Yap, I got the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'variable variables' feature available in php [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).
Your code will be similar to this:

```
$varName  = 'q' . $i;
$$varName = $_POST[$varName]
```

Also, check out the [extract function](http://php.net/extract)

Comment: This would work, but it just *feels* wrong to do it this way unless you are forced to not use array for some reason. +1 for a valid answer, though not one I agree with.

Comment: i agree with you, variable variables are never safe

Comment: Thanks but wanted to avoid using variable variables if poss.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    ${"q$i"} = $_POST["q$i"];
}
echo $q1;
```

Using variable variables can easily assign $q1

Answer (score 0):

Would defining your **$q** variables as an array help?

```
$q[i] = $_POST["q".$i.""];
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you want to create the variable names dynamically?
like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
   $varname = "q" . $i;
   $$varname = $_POST["q".$i.""];
}
print $q2;
```